# Why doesn't buffer overflow occur with GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, buffer, buffer-overflow

I was just recently learning about buffer overflows. I was attempting to replicate it using GCC. Here's the code I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];

    strcpy(buffer_one, "one");
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two");

    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains %s\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains %s\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and contains %d\n\n", value, value);

    printf("[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]);

    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains %s\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains %s\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and contains %d\n\n", value, value);

    return 0;
}
```

Seems like it should work, right? Buffer_two and buffer_one are adjacent from each other in memory.

```
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0x7fff56ff2b68 and contains two
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0x7fff56ff2b70 and contains one
[BEFORE] value is at 0x5 and contains 5
```

However, shortly following this…

```
[STRCPY] copying 14 bytes into buffer_two

Abort trap: 6
```

How come C recognizes this? And how can some hackers execute more complex buffer overflows that actually work?

Comment: C (or C++) *doesn't* recognize that. Neither language have bounds checking on C-strings or arrays, not standardized anyway. Writing out of bounds of anything leads to *undefined behavior* meaning anything could happen.

Comment: It is impossible to answer definitely without the generated assembly for your code (`gcc -S`), and once provided, the answer should be clear enough that no question is necessary.

Comment: What platform, version of gcc, and compile/link command line are you using?

Comment: check how you run your program, probably you're forcing some runtime check. See how it works here http://ideone.com/wQHItj  . Also note that on ideone stack grows in opposite direction.

Comment: @MichaelBurr OS 10.10.2, latest version of GCC 4.2.1

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you've successfuly produced a buffer overflow by *attempting* to write `14` `char`s in a memory region of `8` `char`s.

As soon as you write past the allocated memory, the behaviour goes undefined. So, the `Abort` message is there.

Related: [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

> *Why doesn't buffer overflow occur with GCC?*

Well, it **is** happenning in your case. That's why, as a *side effect* you can see the *Abort* message.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when a buffer overflow occurs is [undefined](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). That means that anything might happen. For instance, [demons may fly from your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

What happened here is that your program crashed. Rather boring.

Comment: How do you link your nose together with your program though?

Comment: @Lundin Now, asking that question will result in UB. :-D